# Over lapping of timeseries on x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

[image]

```
     import pandas as pd
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     import numpy as np
     load_file=pd.read_excel(r'E:\CCNC\CCNCCodes\Modulated 
     output\plot_oriented_ss_data.xlsx',header=0)
     load_file.columns
     s=load_file.loc[0:49,['Timeseries','ccn_0.1']] s
     s1=s
     s['Timeseries'] = s['Timeseries'].astype(str)
     plt.plot(s1[0:49]['Timeseries'],s1[0:5762]['ccn_0.1'],color='b')

     plt.grid()
     plt.show()
```

Please tell me where do I exact need to make the change to avoid the overlapping of time series in x-axis.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting your 'Timeseries' to `str`, you should convert them to `datetime` using:

```
s['Timeseries'] = pd.to_datetime(s['Timeseries'])
```

Comment: You may need to include the `format` parameter: `pd.to_datetime(s['Timeseries'], format="%H:%M:%S")`